# Color in case environment

Tags: color

How can I change the color of {(case) in the below code?

```
\begin{equation}\label{48ch}
 \begin{cases}

  \sigma_1>0  \\
  \sigma_2<0 \\

   \end{cases} 
  \end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome. Can you attachment all your code?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{48ch}
    {\color{green}
\begin{cases}
    {\color{red}\sigma_1}>{\color{yellow}0}  \\[1ex]
    {\color{blue}\sigma_2}<{\color{purple}0}    
\end{cases}
}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a coloured brace, you can load  `empheq` and use an `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left =\color{red}\empheqlbrace]{equation}\label{48ch}
  \begin{aligned}
      & \sigma_1 > 0 \\[1ex]
      & \sigma_2 < 0
  \end{aligned}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, what you like to have colored. Maybe something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{48ch}
{\color{red}
\begin{cases}
    \sigma_1>0  \\[1ex]
    \sigma_2<0    
\end{cases}
}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```